# jxls, Jasper Report or BIRT

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I want to use a template base reporting framework like: jxls, Jasper Report or BIRT in a javaee application because it allows me to modify only the templates for satisfying customer requirements and without recompiling the java source code.

I use jxls, but I have a dynamic query and the number of output columns varies time to time so the database result set is transformed to:

```
List<Object[]>
```

. For generating excel report the following code added to the excel temple:

```html
<jx:forEach items="${rows}" var="row">
    <jx:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">  ${cell} </jx:forEach>
</jx:forEach>
```

But If I have a list with more than 1000 elements it gives timeout exception.

What do you think? What is the problem? Is jxls a bad choice?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you go with Jxls you should use Jxls-2 which was recently released.
Jxls-2 has much better performance and much more flexible if you need to create dynamic columns.
Check [Dynamic Columns example](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/7da317a36934cf54b919aa8a51c371e49a0f7b5e/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/DynamicColumnsDemo.java?at=master) in [Jxls Demo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo) project which shows an example of how to generate dynamic columns with [Jxls-2](http://jxls.sf.net).

The example uses [XML config](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/7da317a36934cf54b919aa8a51c371e49a0f7b5e/src/main/resources/org/jxls/demo/dynamic_columns_demo.xml?at=master) to build the [Jxls Commands](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/main_concepts.html) but you can also construct them using Java API or Excel markup.

The [XML config](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/7da317a36934cf54b919aa8a51c371e49a0f7b5e/src/main/resources/org/jxls/demo/dynamic_columns_demo.xml?at=master) looks like this

```
<xls>
    <area ref="Template!A1:B4">
        <each items="headers" var="header" ref="Template!A3:A3" dir="RIGHT">
            <area ref="Template!A3:A3"/>
        </each>
        <each items="rows" var="row" ref="Template!A4:A4">
            <area ref="Template!A4:A4">
                <each items="row" var="cell" ref="Template!A4:A4" dir="RIGHT">
                    <area ref="Template!A4:A4"/>
                </each>
            </area>
        </each>
    </area>
</xls>
```

The [template Excel file](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/7da317a36934cf54b919aa8a51c371e49a0f7b5e/src/main/resources/org/jxls/demo/dynamic_columns_demo.xls?at=master) in this case is very simple and contains a markup only in 2 cells (for header and for data):

```
${header}

${cell}
```

The java code reads the template and builds [XlsArea](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/javadoc/jxls/org/jxls/area/XlsArea.html) for processing

```
    InputStream is = DynamicColumnsDemo.class.getResourceAsStream(TEMPLATE);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, os);
    InputStream configInputStream = DynamicColumnsDemo.class.getResourceAsStream(DYNAMIC_COLUMNS_DEMO_XML_CONFIG);
    AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XmlAreaBuilder(configInputStream, transformer);
    List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
    Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
```

Next it sets the required data into the context and applies the transformation to the source area

```
    // creating context
    Context context = transformer.createInitialContext();
    context.putVar("headers", headers);
    context.putVar("rows", rows);
    // applying transformation
    logger.info("Applying area " + xlsArea.getAreaRef() + " at cell " + new CellRef("Result!A1"));
    xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Result!A1"), context);
```

The result of the transformation is a table filled with dynamic data values for table headers, columns and rows.